# Messing up the table views section

Tags: ios, swift

After watching a lot of tutorials on how the make a good looking table view on youtube, i can't understand why my tableview looks like it does when i run the app. It might be something on the storyboard?

Here's my code

```
let opskrifterArray = ["Hello world", "Hello world", "Hello world", "Hello world"]


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as UITableViewCell!

    let textlabeltwo = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
    textlabeltwo.text = opskrifterArray[indexPath.row]




    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.opskrifterArray.count
}
```

And when i run the app it looks like this
[image]

[image]

Comment: can you add a screenshot of your storyboard settings ?

Comment: You can see the settings now

Comment: Have you tried to implemenet hieghtForRowAtIndexPath ?

Comment: Doesn't work. Still messed up in the sections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separator size is too small to display inside scaled Simulator. Try to press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to see it in real resolution.

Answer (score 0):

I think your tag is conflicting , tag must be unique